# How does one say "one of the artists" if the one referred to is female and the group of artists is either an all female group or a mixed group?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, género, concordancia-gramatical

Here are a couple of scenarios to paint a clearer picture:

I want to refer to a female artist among many female artists.  Would the following be correct:

> una de las artistas

?

I want to refer to a female artist among a group of artists of various genders.  Would the following be correct:

> una de ***los*** artistas

?

---

**¿Cómo se dice "one of the artists" si el que se refiere es femenino y el grupo de artistas es un grupo totalmente femenino o un grupo mixto?**

Aquí están un par de escenarios para clarificar:

Quiero referirme a una artista femenina entre muchas artistas femeninas.  ¿La siguiente sería correcta?

> una de las artistas

Quiero referirme a una artista femenina entre un grupo de artistas de varios géneros.  ¿La siguiente sería correcta?

> una de ***los*** artistas

Comment: https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/una-de-los-2/

Comment: La información en la página conectada a tu enlace es muy útil, @guifa.  Te agradezco sinceramente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En español es habitual utilizar el masculino como género no marcado, es decir, como género "neutro". Esto aplica no solo a los artículos y determinantes, sino también a los nombres plurales e incluso a los singulares cuando se emplean en contextos genéricos.
Cito de la *Nueva gramática de la lengua española* (RAE, 2009):

> [**2.2k**](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=PMTsApdccFaxssTP) [...] Se obtiene así mismo el uso no marcado del masculino con muchos sustantivos singulares usados en contextos genéricos. [...] De acuerdo con ellos, es genérica la primera de estas dos oraciones, pero no la segunda: ***Un estudiante universitario*** tiene que esforzarse mucho hoy en día para trabajar y estudiar a la vez; ***Un estudiante universitario*** publicó hace unos días una carta de protesta en este diario. Consecuentemente, la expresión subrayada en el primer ejemplo [en negrita] incluye a hombres y mujeres, mientras que la subrayada en el segundo caso [en negrita] solo se refiere a un varón.

Debido a este uso tan establecido del masculino como género no marcado, se puede dar el caso en que los hablantes, dentro del mismo contexto sintáctico, pasen de manera natural de usar el femenino para un individuo concreto a usar el masculino para el grupo al que pertenece (cuando este es mixto); este uso está recogido por la RAE y no se considera incorrecto, pero sí infrecuente y muy forzado:

> Como resultado del carácter no marcado del género masculino, no son anómalas expresiones como *Su último hijo ha sido una niña*, que resultarían irregulares si esa no fuera una propiedad firmemente arraigada en el sistema gramatical del español. Aun así, es muy infrecuente la discordancia del género en las construcciones partitivas. Para decir de una mujer que destaca entre un conjunto de alumnos y alumnas, se registran a veces oraciones como *Usted es una de los alumnos más brillantes de que goza la Facultad* (Bain, *Dolor*), pero la falta de concordancia entre *una* (femenino) y *los* (masculino) hace que la construcción resulte muy forzada.

En cuanto al uso del femenino *las* para referirse a un grupo mixto de *artistas*, dice la RAE:

> [**2.5b**](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=yelvjWmykbVhjxQr) Son comunes en cuanto al género los sustantivos de persona que designan tanto a hombres como a mujeres. En esta clase se encuentran la mayor parte de los sustantivos de persona acabados en *-a*, con muy escasas excepciones, que se tratarán en el §2.5e. Se dice, pues, *un atleta* y *una atleta*, y se forman, análogamente, expresiones como *sus prestigiosos colegas* y *sus prestigiosas colegas*.

Ni el mencionado punto 2.5e ni el resto de los incluidos en los epígrafes 2.5 y 2.6 mencionan el sustantivo *artista* como excepción, por lo que podemos considerarlo como un sustantivo común en cuanto a género: *el artista, la artista, los artistas, las artistas, un artista, una artista, unos artistas,* etc. Sin embargo, no hay que olvidar lo dicho antes sobre el género no marcado: en español, corresponde al masculino. Se entiende, pues, que al especificar el género femenino diciendo *las artistas* lo que estamos dando a entender es que el grupo de artistas es femenino en su totalidad; esto es, que todas son mujeres. Si queremos expresar que es un grupo mixto, siguiendo la norma anterior, lo correcto sería decir *los artistas* empleando el masculino como género no marcado.

Por tanto, y retomando el ejemplo de la pregunta planteada:

- *Una de los artistas* → Correcto, aunque algo forzado.
- *Uno de los artistas* → Correcto.
- *Una de las artistas* → Correcto solo si todas las artistas son mujeres.

---

<sub>El debate sobre el choque entre el concepto social de "igualdad de género" y el uso gramatical del género masculino como género no marcado no es nuevo. La edición de la *Gramática* arriba citada es de hace diez años, pero hoy en día pueden encontrarse usos del género gramatical femenino en casos en los que la RAE no lo contempla, ya sea forzando la diferenciación de género en sustantivos comunes (como en "portavoza") o empleándolo para referirse a un grupo mixto (como en "estamos todas de acuerdo" en un grupo de padres y madres).

Que tales usos se acepten en un futuro como válidos, dependerá de que arraiguen o no en el habla popular.</sub>

Comment: Es evidente que ha habido casos en que el uso genérico no parece tan genérico, siendo necesario recalcar la femenidad de la partitiva.  Por ejemplo: *Salamón, que fue tan sabio, ¿no se enamoró de **una** de los gentiles y ella le hizo ydolatrar?* — La penitencia de amor (1514, Pedro Manuel de Urrea)

Comment: *Praxilla Sicyonia, Poetisa, y **una** de los nueve Poetas Lyricos Griegos…* — Memorias para la Historia de la poesía y poetas españoles (1745, Fray Martín Sarmiento)

Comment: (es decir, no es fenómeno nuevo, definitivamente hay escritores importantes a que la incongruencia de «uno (pero mujer) de los» les ha parecido demasiado chocante y «una de los» mucho menos)

Comment: ¡Esfuerzo encomiable, @walen!  Esta vez, ¡¡te otorgo la codiciada marca verde sin vacilación!!

Answer (score 1):

Though I am attempting to answer my own question, I do not consider it a sufficient answer because I am simply using a lack of evidence in online searches as a basis for understanding the Spanish language.  While this can be helpful, it cannot exclusively rule out certain speech patterns that simply are not found on the web.  Even so, perhaps what I have observed will help someone reading this and suffice until a better answer can be provided.

Initially, I had thought that

> una de los artistas

would be an acceptable way to refer to a female artist among a group of artists of various genders.  However, since I was not able to find any examples of

> una de ***los*** artistas

I had to conclude that this is simply not said this way in Spanish.

On the other hand, I was able to find several examples of

> ***uno*** de ***los*** artistas

(And, of course, several for ***una** de **las** artistas*.)

All of this draws me to the conclusion that in constructs of this nature:

> INDEFININTE PRONOUN
>
> +
>
> "of the"
>
> +
>
> PLURAL FORM OF A NOUN OF VARIABLE GENDER* (to which the indefinite pronoun belongs)

you have to stick with the same gender used for the indefinite pronoun.

*What I am referring to here is "[**invariant nouns**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_nouns#Noun_gender)" or *[**sustantivos de género común**](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/G%C3%A9nero_gramatical#Dos_g.C3.A9neros.2C_una_forma)*.

If you are a native speaker of Spanish, or simply know enough about the Spanish language to refute or support this answer, please comment and/or add an answer of your own.  If you can cite some sources on any rules governing this, even better.

Answer (score 0):

Si el grupo es totalmente femenino: "una de las artistas"
Si el grupo es mixto : "uno de los artistas", aunque "una de los artistas" es correcto suena extraño y forzado

Comment: No veo como añade nada nuevo esta respuesta dado el resto de respuestas que tiene la pregunta